# Eigenvalue spectrum of $L_x+iL_y$

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is it possible to find out the generic eigenvalue spectrum of the non-Hermitian operator $L_x+iL_y$, without using any representation?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that $(L_x,L_y,L_z)$ satisfy the usual angular momentum algebra. Then, one knows that all states can be labelled by the eigenvalues of $(L^2,L_z)$. Pick such a state and label it as $|j,m\rangle$ where the $L^2$ eigenvalue is $j(j+1)$ and the $L_z$ eigenvalue is $m$. Note that we have not made any assumption about the allowed values of $(j,m)$. The action of $L_\pm$ produces states $|j,m\pm1\rangle$. This can be continued to get an infinite set of states. Several possibilities occur:

1. The process of raising using $L_+$ terminates at some state -- call it the highest weight state (the norm of $L_+$ on the highest weight state is zero) .
2. The process of lowering using $L_-$ terminates at some state  -- call it the lowest weight(the norm of $L_-$ on the lowest weight state is zero).

Recall that the groups $SU(2)$ and $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ arise from the same Lie algebra (over $\mathbb{C}$). So the above construction holds for both of them. Unitarity (each state in the irrep has positive norm) decides on the allowed values of $(j,m)$. For $SU(2)$, all unitary irreps  have an highest and lowest weight state. However, for $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, the unitary irreps are different. In particular, they are infinite dimensional. For instance, one could have a highest weight state but no lowest weight state. You can look up unitary irreps of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ to see all the cases. See here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SL2%28R%29

Comment: I think the OP is asking "What, if any, are the eigenvalues of L_+?"  So, it's not clear to me how this answers the question.

Comment: Yeah, I am answering something totally different. Thanks.:-) @roopam: What is the meaning of a non-hermitian operator if there is no vector/Hilbert space on which it can act? What defines $L_+$?

Comment: I think he's simply asking "given a representation $\rho$ of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$ on a vector space $V$, what are the eigenvalues of $\rho(L_+)$?" (but I could be wrong).  In this case, I'm fairly certain that all of the eigenvalues are zero.

Comment: Then, the only possible eigenvalue is zero and any highest weight state is an eigenvector.

Comment: @joshphysics- Thanks. But how did you conclude that **all the** eigenvalues will be zero? Is it trivial to guess?

Comment: Use the commutator $[L_z,L_+]$ to show that $L_+$ maps any state to an orthogonal state. So it has no diagonal entries and its matrix representation will be upper triangular with zero on the diagonals.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a complete answer, but here's my stab at it:

Looking for the eigenstates and eigenvalues of $L_-$.
These might be something analogous to to the coherent states of quantum optics: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states)

Where $L_-$ takes the role of the annihilation operator, and the Fock states become the eigenstates of $L_z$. I'm still not sure what role the total angular momentum plays here, or the physical interpretation of such a sate.  You could construct such something close to such a sate from a superposition of $m$ values for a very high $n$ Rydberg state.

Still think I'm missing something though